# Compare interval date by row

Tags: postgresql, date, aggregate-functions, intervals, window-functions

I am trying to group dates within a 1 year interval given an identifier by labeling which is the earliest date and which is the latest date. If there are no dates within a 1 year interval from that date, then it will record it's own date as the first and last date. For example originally the data is:

```
id | date 
____________
a  | 1/1/2000
a  | 1/2/2001
a  | 1/6/2000
b  | 1/3/2001
b  | 1/3/2000
b  | 1/3/1999
c  | 1/1/2000
c  | 1/1/2002
c  | 1/1/2003
```

And the output I want is:

```
id  | first_date | last_date
___________________________
a   | 1/1/2000   | 1/2/2001
b   | 1/3/1999   | 1/3/2001
c   | 1/1/2000   | 1/1/2000
c   | 1/1/2002   | 1/1/2003
```

I have been trying to figure this out the whole day and can't figure it out. I can do it for cases id's with only 2 duplicates, but can't for greater values. Any help would be great.

Comment: You forgot to specify the date format (not ISO, so much is clear), your version of Postgres and your best shot at the query (even if it's not working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , min(min_date) AS min_date
     , max(max_date) AS max_date
     , sum(row_ct)   AS row_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT id, year, min_date, max_date, row_ct
        , year - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT id
           , extract(year FROM the_date)::int AS year
           , min(the_date) AS min_date
           , max(the_date) AS max_date
           , count(*)      AS row_ct
      FROM   tbl
      GROUP  BY id, year
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY id, grp
ORDER  BY id, grp;
```

1) Group all rows per (`id, year`), in subquery **`sub1`**. Record min and max of the date. I added a count of rows (`row_ct`) for demonstration.

2) Subtract the `row_number()` from the year in the second subquery **`sub2`**. Thus, all rows in succession end up in the same group (`grp`). A gap in the years starts a new group.

3) In the **final `SELECT`**, group a second time, this time by (`id, grp`) and record min, max and row count again. Voilá. Produces exactly the result you are looking for.

**[-> SQLfiddle demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/41b4b/4)**

Related answers:
[Return array of years as year ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533040/return-array-of-years-as-year-ranges/17533742#17533742)
[Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010348/group-by-repeating-attribute/14016575#14016575)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, min ([date]) first_date, max([date]) last_date
from <yourTbl> group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/26b1e/1)):

```
SELECT id,
    min(date) AS first_date,
    max(date) AS last_date
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```